# error in if condition using python

Tags: python, html, mysql, apache, localhost

I am  beginner to python , I have simple code to insert into database or delete user information from database .I am using HTML form to get  user information,and python code to delete or insert user information into database .My HTML form have two submit type button add and delete.

I am using if condition to perform action depending on which button is pressed .(Python3.4,Mysql.connector,running in localhost)

Python code:

```
#!"C:\python34\python.exe"
import cgitb ,cgi
import sys
import mysql.connector
cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
addres = form.getvalue('addres')
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()
#print(form)
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',port='8051',
                                       database='tabl',
                                       user='root',
                                       password='new')
cursor = conn.cursor()
if "add" in form:
    cursor.execute("""insert into tablename values (%s, %s)""",(first_name,addres))
    print("inserted")

elif "delete" in form:
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE fname=%s and location = %s",(first_name,addres))
    print("deleted")

else:
    print ("Couldn't determine which button was pressed.")  

conn.commit()
```

In if condition i have given print statement to print if it's inserted or deleted.But it won't print that statements instead it will give server error.If i remove those print statements it will work.

Can please suggest what is a mistake in above code , or other way of writing .

error as:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
End of script output before headers: python3.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
```

Comment: Did you check your Apache's error log for the error message?

Comment: @KlausD. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @BK435 ya i downloaded and installed.

Comment: ya i can insert into databse

Comment: ya i have...if i remove those print statements,it  won't give any error it will insert or delete into databse .But i want those print statements also.

Comment: no i am not sending it back to html form .just printing in same page console

Comment: @BK435 that  means i am not returning into any other pages